# how to define the secured URLs within an application dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring framework version: 3.2.3.RELEASE and
Spring security version: 3.2.3.RELEASE

I want to define the secured URLs within an application dynamically,and I have tried for several ways . I just can't make it,please help me!

According to http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#faq-dynamic-url-metadata ,
I learn that dynamically defining access control to URLs needs using an explicitly declared security filter chain in order to customize the FilterSecurityInterceptor bean.
My question is

1. how to explicitly declared security filter chain？are there any example?
2. according to the book [Spring security 3.1](http://www.packtpub.com/spring-security-3-1/book)
   which said"We can use a custom `BeanPostProcessor` to replace the standard       `FilterInvocationServiceSecurityMetadataSource` with our custom  implementation."

I followed this way and it dosen't work, I wondering if I have done something wrong?

the Java config class looks like this:

```
 public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    }

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")                               
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }


    @Configuration                                                   
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin();
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class KpiFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Autowired
    private KpiFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource metadataSource;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if(bean instanceof FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource) {
            return metadataSource;
        }
        if(bean instanceof FilterChainProxy.FilterChainValidator) {
            return new FilterChainProxy.FilterChainValidator() {
                @Override
                public void validate(FilterChainProxy filterChainProxy) {

                }
            };
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

I found a method `withObjectPostProcessor`,and try to do the following,it still doesn't worked. so what is best way to leverage this method?

```
@Configuration
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private KpiFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource metadataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/signup/**", "/about", "/login/**", "/index")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .permitAll()
                    .loginPage("/login/form")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("policeNo")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .failureUrl("/login/form?error")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/default")
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login/form?logout")
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .withObjectPostProcessor(
                        new ObjectPostProcessor<FilterSecurityInterceptor>() {
                                public <O extends FilterSecurityInterceptor> O postProcess(
                                        O fsi) {
                                    fsi.setSecurityMetadataSource(metadataSource);
                                    return fsi;
                                }
                            });
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
            webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for your question?